# Cmake errors of installing ccons

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake, compiler-flags

After I execute `cmake CMakeLists.txt`, which seems to give no errors, I run make which gives me the following error:

```
:/usr/local/src/llvm-3.1.src/tools/ccons$ sudo make
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ccons.dir/ccons.cpp.o
/usr/local/src/llvm-3.1.src/tools/ccons/ccons.cpp:1:0: error: bad value (x86_64) for -march= swi
tch
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ccons.dir/ccons.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ccons.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there any way to figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, why are you building the software using `sudo`? That's asking for trouble. You should only need `sudo` when you're installing (i.e., `sudo make install`).

For whatever reason, your compiler appears to be passed the flag `-march=x86_64`, which it thinks is invalid. To see what flags CMake is trying to compile with, do the following:

1. Run `make edit_cache`.
2. Press `t` to switch on advanced mode. This lets you see additional cache variables.
3. Look for the variables that start with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. There are different ones for different build types, but one of them will probably have this `-march=x64_64` flag in it.

Good luck.

Comment: I follow your setup,but stuck at step 1, it gives me `make: *** No rule to make target `edit_cache'.  Stop.`

Comment: FYI the reason that I'm using `sudo` is that I don't have the privilege to write to /usr/local/src folder as my current user

Comment: I normally build sources in some directory that I can write to as myself, because that means some malicious `Makefile` won't trash your system. As to your first problem, can you confirm that you ran `cmake` without error? Do you have a `Makefile` in your build directory?

Comment: Sorry for this tardy reply. I just get used to follow to tutorial online that alway curl the source code into `/usr/local/src`, Are you suggesting put into `~/usr/local/src`

Comment: I think in the step 2, you mean press 'y'

Comment: I found this issue in the official website http://code.google.com/p/ccons/issues/detail?id=9 I don't know how to use a patch file

Comment: I got the information Please provide any additional information below.

The "special steps" taken in the PKGBUILD are these:
1. Copy ccons to the llvm/tools folder
2. Removing -march from CMakeLists.txt:
sed -i 's/ -march=${LLVM_HOST_ARCH}//' CMakeLists.txt
3. Specifying clang as the compiler:
CXX=clang++ CC=clang make

Even with -march or without CC=clang, ccons does not compile here.

Comment: This is the new error I got  /usr/local/src/llvm-3.1.src/tools/ccons/ccons.cpp:17:33: fatal error: llvm/System/Signals.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: 1. Yes, it's better to build sources out of your home directory. 2. I definitely mean 't': in ccmake (the ncurses interface to cmake), it switches to advanced mode. 3. I googled "patch file" and instructions for using them is in the first result. 4. I don't know the ccons build system specifically. 5. Looks like it's not setting the include path for some reason. Why? I don't know.